# My PC gets laggy and monitor crashes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, crash

I am using Ubuntu as my only OS. I've deleted Windows 10 and started using Ubuntu 20.04 recently. However, I experience a problem that has never occured in my previous OS. What happens is basicaly, out of nowhere my mouse slows down as if my FPS drops to 5. This happens while I'm browsing internet, using discord and doing basic things. Then, my monitor crashes with the message
**"Display port no signal"**. After that, I have to reboot my computer in order to get display from my monitor.

What might be the reason? I checked all the cables but there is no disconnection.This happened only on Ubuntu. When I used to use 18.04 I didn't experience this problem.
I've deleted Ubuntu and checked it for Windows 10 if the same problem occurs but it seems like it only happens on Ubuntu. I use RX570 as GPU and Ryzen5 2600 as CPU. No matter what I did on Windows 10(played games on ultra graphics settings etc.), I have never experienced such problem. Hence, I think it is not a hardware problem. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Update: I have installed the latest compatible AMD drivers. However, the problem still continues.

Update 2: I solved the problem.

Solution of the problem: Install Ubuntu 20.04 with minimal installation without updating and installing third party drivers during the installation. After that, install the latest official AMD drivers for your GPU.

Comment: Same here. I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 and then 20.04 for several months until the last few days when it crashed while I was sharing screen. Although Chrome says "Applications closes unexpectedly" but it really didn't close. Every time I experienced this, it was accompanied by large black pixels appearing on my screen! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are using the AMD proprietory graphics driver. Do not use the free driver software.

Comment: I still have the same problem even though I have installed the latest compatible AMD drivers.

Comment: Maybe Ubuntu does not support your pc. You may install another OS: Debian is an option. But still there is no guarantee that your problem will be solved, as Ubuntu is based on Debian